# How to make single control for a label used on all the pages in an application?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need a single control for a label (as a footer) used on all the pages in an application, how is it possible? Do I need to take custom control? How to do it?

I have created a ContentView as custom.cs

```
namespace App1
{


    public class Custom : ContentView
    {
        public Label TitleLabel { get; private set; }

        public Switch EnabledSwitch { get; private set; }

        public Custom(string title)
        {
            TitleLabel = new Label()
            {

                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Text = title
            };

            EnabledSwitch = new Switch()
            {

            };

            var selector = new StackLayout()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Padding = 10,
                Children = {
                TitleLabel,
                EnabledSwitch
                },
            };

            Content = selector;
        }
    }

}
```

now I need to access it's label to my XAML pages like login and other pages.
How can I do so?

Comment: what have you tried? Do you just need to add an identical footer to every page? Is it just a label? You could try making a custom page that all your other pages inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define xmlns namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlSamples.Controls;assembly=XamlSamples"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             x:Class="XamlSamples.Views.TestPage"
             Title="TestPage"">

  <StackLayout>
    <local:Custom YourProperty="something"/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

- For XAML your view must have parameterless constructor
- Also use Bindable Properties : http://xamandor.me/2015/02/27/custom-controls-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: can i take custom.cs file in xaml? if yes, then how?

Comment: i can write it in xaml, how can i give Text="some" property and others to this custom control? what to do for this? help me, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at link I provided inc comment.

Comment: How can i use Font property to this custom control?

Comment: Read more about bindable properties. You should add a new Font property and handle its changes (change font of labels etc). If the answer is working for you, you can mark this question as answered. Thanks!